# What does a Hadoop job id mean?

Tags: hadoop

When a Hadoop job is created, it's assigned  unique id.  For example, I just ran a job with the id `job_201709221002_0046`.  It seems like the first part is some sort of timestamp, but it's not the date that the job was submitted. The part after the underscore seems to be sequential.  **What does this date mean?**

Edit: The job I was looking at was a week old.  I just submitted a new one at Fri Oct 20 12:22:03 PDT 2017 and it was assigned the job id `job_201709221002_0047`.

Comment: What was the date submitted? that could clarify things. I'd say something like the date submitted in UTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Represents the time when the JobTracker was started.In your case `job_201709221002_0047` it is the 47th job running at the jobtracker which was started at the time 201709221002

[Source](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobID.html)

*JobID represents the immutable and unique identifier for the job. JobID consists of two parts. First part represents the jobtracker identifier, so that jobID to jobtracker map is defined. For cluster setup this string is the jobtracker start time, for local setting, it is "local". Second part of the JobID is the job number.*

*An example JobID is : job_200707121733_0003 , which represents the third job running at the jobtracker started at 200707121733.*